# MySQL Two Table Min Value and Group By

Tags: mysql, group-by, subquery

I have two tables, products, and products_description

Products:

```
Product_ID    Product_Price
 1             10    
 2             20    
 3             10    
 4             20   
 5             10    
 6             20
 7             10    
 8             10   
 9             10    
10             10
```

Products_Description:

```
Product_ID    Product_Name
 1             Pants - Black    
 2             Pants - Black    
 3             Pants - White    
 4             Pants - White   
 5             Pants - Red    
 6             Pants - Red
 7             Hat    
 8             Socks   
 9             Scarf    
10             Bird
```

Basically I need to implement code with respect to the current code that's already present in the shopping cart.

The implementation needs to GROUP BY products_name - but provide the cheapest one.

So far I've got the following:

```
SELECT  p.products_id, p.products_price, pd.products_name

FROM products p
```

// bof custom sub-query

```
join
(
SELECT pp.products_id, pp.products_name, min(pr.products_price) as min_price
from products_description pp
inner JOIN products pr 
ON pp.products_id = pr.products_id
group by pp.products_name
)
AS subq on p.products_id = subq.products_id and p.products_price = subq.min_price
```

// eof custom sub-query

```
LEFT JOIN products_description pd on p.products_id = pd.products_id
```

Desired output:

```
Product_ID    Product_Name    Product_Price
 1             Pants - Black   10 
 3             Pants - White   10 
 5             Pants - Red     10
 7             Hat             10   
 8             Socks           10
 9             Scarf           10  
10             Bird            10
```

But what's happening is the pants is getting removed. And only products 7 - 10 are remaining behind....

Any ideas anyone please?

Comment: "The implementation needs to GROUP BY products_name - but provide the cheapest one." what? Sounds like you are trying to work around a problem with DB design? You don't normally group products....

Comment: I kind of have a very specific need to do so. It's not a problem with DB design.

Comment: That's not how it looks from example data...

Comment: The example data is purely example data. Those are not even the products that will be listed. If you need an explanation, two versions of the same product will be sold - one secondhand, one brand new. I want the cheapest product to be displayed. And I do not want to add a prefix/suffix to indicate whether it is brand new or secondhand, that will be handled on the product page itself.

Comment: The out side join with subq should not use the product id.

Comment: @Tim3880 If I remove that, I get duplicates of each product.

Comment: Don't u want duplicates (1 good one, 1 crappy one)?

Comment: it seems your code returns correct result. What's your output?

Comment: @Tim3880 my code removes all the pants completely. It just shows the other products that don't have another product with the same name.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b3399/2

Comment: @Tim3880 Okay, now edit the fiddle, change all the pants that are 20 (in price) to 5. And then run the SQL and you'll see what happens :/

Comment: yes i saw the problem. that's what i meant you can't join by product id since they are not the ones with min-price.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want the cheapest product for each product name.  The query is a bit complicated because the price and name information are separated.  One way of writing the query is as:

```
select p.Product_ID, ppd.Product_Name, p.price
from product_description pd join
     products p
     on pd.product_id = p.product_id join
     (select pd2.Product_name, min(p2.price) as minprice
      from product_description pd2 join
           products p2
           on pd2.product_id = p2.product_id
      group by pd2.Product_name
     ) ppd
     on ppd.Product_Name = pd.Product_Name and
        ppd.minprice = p.price;
```